# Reverse DNS (PTR) for Email

Tags: domain-name-system, email, smtp, godaddy, ptr-record

We are hosting our website (http://www.redappleapartments.com) with a hosting company in Sweden. And we are using godaddy as our email provider. So, our smtp servers are

```
smtp.europe.secureserver.net
mailstore1.europe.secureserver.net
```

Our website sends plenty of emails to our customers and we are sending via godaddy (using SMTP authentication). Some of the emails are never delivered to the recipients. And sometimes we see such warning:

```
The hostname in the SMTP greeting does not match the reverse DNS (PTR)
```

Can somebody out there suggest how we can solve this problem?

Comment: You'll want to speak with the people you're relaying through.. godaddy in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the SMTP servers of Godaddy there is a limit on the number of messages that it will relay. The godaddy site says the limit is 250 but in our experience it doesn't push out more than 80 mails per day.

You should set up the RDNS / PTR records on your authoritative DNS servers and not 3rd party DNS servers. Use DIG  to find your authoritative DNS servers.

Setting up the RDNS or PTR record is as follows.

1. Create an RDNS zone
2. (If your ip address is 123.456.789.81)
3. Drop the last octet and reverse the string so the RDNS is 789.456.123
4. Append .in-addr.arpa to the string above to get 789.456.123.in-addr.arpa. This is the hostname for the RDNS zone
5. Add a new PTR record use the last octet of your ip address 81 for the name. Enter the domain name for the CNAME.

If your site is sending out a large number of emails roll your own mail server its a lot easier than you think.

Comment: Its not the relay problem. As if godaddy does not accept the mail because of over used quota, the mail is not sent until the next day. And all of the emails are bcc to us, so we can see the mail has been sent.

And regarding this PTR record, we already have one PTR record in the DNS. Which is to our VPS IP address. 

Do you think we need to add another for the SMTP server(s). Sorry, my knowledge regarding DNS is very poor.

Comment: If thats the case then create an "A" record with the correct HOST name so that it matches the PTR record.

Comment: Check the "A" record and the "MX" records you'll know what to do.

Comment: theres no ptr option in godaddy dns settings

Answer (score 0):

Where do you see the warning? Is that in the logs or in an NDR?

My first thought here is that if you are using the GoDaddy servers that it may be that one(?) or more of their servers (as I imagine they must have more than a few sending servers) that happen to be the last hop out for your mail are missing PTR records. First step is to try and identify which IP to hostname mismatch it is complaining about. With that information in hand, it should be a simple matter of verifying PTR records.

If you find that it is for a server you have control over the DNS, you can correct. If it is one of theirs, they will have to correct.

Answer (score 0):

If your "VPS" ( Linux, or windows) is hosted in Godaddy, you should config the "PTR DNS" in godaddy.

If your "VPS" is hosted in Linode, AWS, or google cloud, you should config the 'PTR DNS' in these ISPs. (e.g. Linode, AWS, google cloud...)